# Proving that the order of a group is greater than or equal to the product of orders of 2 subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that $H \cap K = \{e\}$

Prove that $|G|\ge |H||K|$

What I think is the correct step is to consider the cosets $hK, h \in H$, and then using properties of cosets to prove that the product of orders can't be greater than $|G|$, but this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$, let $HK = \{hk \, \vert \, h\in H, k\in K\}$. Prove that $|HK| = |H|\cdot |K|/|H\cap K|$. Since $HK$ is a subset of $G$, the desired inequality immediately follows.

Comment: But $|HK|$ is not necessarily equal to $|H||K|$, so can this property be used?

Comment: In this specific instance, you assumed $H\cap K = \{e\}$, so $|H\cap K| = 1$, and $|HK| = |H|\cdot |K|$.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Consider $\phi: H \times K \to G$ given by $\phi(h,k)=hk$. Prove that $\phi$ is injective.